# HashMap vs Map parameter types

Tags: java, types

I've a question regarding using wildcard. I got a compilation error in the "case 3:" line in the switch (illegal start of expression), but that's probably not the root of the problem.
I saw a red line under meleeMap and the two other arguments that "print" method

java.util.HashMap< ? extends Game.Item, java.lang.integer>

can't be applied to

"java.util.Map< Game.MeleeWeapon,java.lang.integer> (and same for RangedWeapon and Armor).

Then I changed the first declaration of those objects from Map to HashMap (after the private) and it solved the problem. The question is why? HashMap implements Map interface, so I thought that it should have worked without changing Map to HashMap, but it didn't work.

```
public class Blacksmith {

private Map<MeleeWeapon,Integer> meleeMap;
private Map<RangedWeapon,Integer> rangedMap;
private Map<Armor,Integer> armorMap;

Blacksmith() {

    meleeMap = new HashMap<MeleeWeapon, Integer>();
    List<MeleeWeapon> meleeList = MeleeWeapon.meleeWeaponList;
    for (MeleeWeapon weapon : meleeList) {
        meleeMap.put(weapon, 5);
    }

    rangedMap = new HashMap<RangedWeapon, Integer>();
    List<RangedWeapon> rangedList = RangedWeapon.rangedWeaponList;
    for (RangedWeapon weapon : rangedList) {
        rangedMap.put(weapon, 5);
    }
    armorMap = new HashMap<Armor, Integer>();
    List<Armor> armorList = Armor.armorList;
    for (Armor armor : armorList) {
        armorMap.put(armor, 2);

    }
}


public void sell(Character customer, Item item){
    System.out.println("1. Melee Weapons");
    System.out.println("2. Ranged Weapons");
    System.out.println("3. Armors");

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int scan = scanner.nextInt();

    switch(scan) {

        case 1:
            print(meleeMap);
            break;
        case 2:
            print(rangedMap);
            break;
        case 3:
            print(armorMap);
        default:
            System.out.println("Wrong input");
    }


    }

    public void print(HashMap<? extends Item,Integer> map){

    for (Item item : map.keySet()){
        System.out.println(item.getName());
    }

}
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a **specific problem** with the **complete error message and/or stacktrace** and the **shortest code necessary** to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: The error are depicted in the question, though I'll do my best to edit the question so it would be clear.

Comment: I do not see a complete error message from a stacktrace in the question anywhere

Comment: illegal start of expression

Comment: you have described an error message you have **NOT** posted the complete error message from the stacktrace that you have to have gotten. One is your interpretation which is fundamentally at question and the other is unambiguous to those that know how to help you.

Comment: illegal start of expression was the compilation error, I just omitted the line number, but mentioned the specific line, so it would be easier to understand where the problem was.  The mismatched arguments is not a compilation error.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson It's somewhat hard to provide a stacktrace you require for a program that doesn't compile, therefore cannot be run, therefore cannot produce any stacktraces. The compile error is in the post right from the start (as seen in edit history). The wording of the question is a bit confusing but the problem statement ("I got compilation error") and error message ("... can't be applied to ...") are both there. What else you find missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your print method specifies HashMap:

```
public void print(HashMap<? extends Item,Integer> map)
```

You probably meant to use Map if you are passing it Map references:

```
public void print(Map<? extends Item,Integer> map)
```

Comment: Why Can't I use HashMap in the method if it's declared as Map before the constructor ?

Comment: Because a `Map` is **not** a `HashMap`

Comment: Right, but HashMap implements Map interface, isn't it ?

Comment: To make it absolutely clear - it's *not* wrong to use `Map`, the thing that needs fixing is the `print()` method - it needs to accept any `Map`, not just `HashMap` implementation of that interface.

Comment: I'd just mention it again - I've figured what's wrong, though I don't fully understand why it solved the problem.

Comment: I think  I understand why .... HashMap isn't any map, while the arguments  were maps. Thanks @JiriTousek

Comment: if you say something must be a `HashMap` a `Map` is **NOT** a `HashMap`